# Producer consumer implementation in a block device driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, block, device-driver, producer-consumer

I'm trying to implement a producer-consumer like situation in my block level driver (on linux kernel version 2.6.39.1). My block driver's `make_request_fn` receives a stream of `struct bio` from a userlevel application. On receiving these BIOs, they are queued up. Next, I create a new `struct bio` which will hold all the information present in the queued BIOs. This new "merged_bio" will be submitted only if there is a `struct request` slot available in the lower level driver's `request_queue`. In the meantime, my block driver will continue to receive BIOs from the userlevel application and will queue them up (a dense load situation). Now, to reduce latency, I want to ensure that as and when BIOs are queued up, a batch comprising of the oldest BIOs are dequeued thereby minimizing idling time in the queue. I am confused as to how I should achieve this pipelined situation (with low per-request latency) wherein my driver's `make_request_fn` is the producer of BIOs and a function calling `submit_bio()` is the consumer of these BIOs. Possible approaches include:

1. **Tasklets** -- Have a tasklet continuously consume BIOs from the queue once a `struct request` slot becomes free in the `request_queue`. This approach won't work because the tasklet handler function is not atomic as it calls `submit_bio()`, which in turn has a call to `schedule()`.
2. **Work queues** -- They can have higher latency than tasklets since the handler function for the work queue can sleep. This could affect my driver's performance since the BIOs may be submitted to the lower level driver at a *much* later time than when it was actually enqueued by the `make_request_fn`. I'm unsure about how large the impact would be on the performance (my driver implements a fast logging device.)
   Another issue with work queues is that how and when to schedule the work queue? The `merged_bio` has to be submitted once the request slot becomes available. So, there has to be some kind of "signaling" mechanism which would schedule the work queue as soon as a `struct request` becomes available. I don't see how the `request_queue` can be monitored continuously for a free slot without a signaling or `poll()`ing mechanism and then explicitly scheduling the work queue. And yes, we cannot call `submit_bio()` from the callback function of the previously completed BIO.
3. **Kernel threads** -- I was considering this as a 3rd option. I don't have much idea about kernel threads, but here is how I was planning to got about it: My driver's `make_request_fn` would continue to enqueue BIOs. A new kernel thread would be created which would continuously consume BIOs from the queue **only** when a `struct request` slot becomes available (and not otherwise). So, each time this kernel thread is scheduled, it would check for an empty request slot and then consume a batch of BIOs from the queue and call `submit_bio()`.
4. **Something more smarter??**

Can members of stackoverflow help me choose a smart and efficient way to implement this scenario? Thank you!

**UPDATE**: I tried the workqueue method but it just resulted in my kernel crashing (/var/log/messages contained garbled text, so I don't have any logs to share). Here is how I went about implementing the workqueue:

The data structure which will be used by the work queue:

```
struct my_work_struct {
   struct work_struct wk;
   pitdev_t *pd;    /* Pointer to my block device */
   int subdev_index;    /* Indexes the disk that is currently in picture -- pd->subdev[subdev_index] */
};

struct pitdev_struct {
/* Driver related data */
struct my_work_struct *work;
} *pd;

typedef struct pitdev_struct pitdev_t;
```

Initialize my work item:

```
/* Allocate memory for both pd and pd->work */

INIT_WORK(&pd->work->wk, my_work_fn);

pd->work->pd = pd;
pd->work->subdev_index = 0;
```

My work function definition:

```
void my_work_fn(struct work_struct *work)
{
   struct my_work_struct *temp = container_of(work, struct my_work_struct, wk);
   pitdev_t *pd = temp->pd;
   int sub_index = temp->subdev_index;

   /* Create a BIO and submit it*/
   submit_bio(WRITE, merged_bio);
}
```

In `merged_bio->bi_end_io`, I schedule my work item:

```
schedule_work(&pd->work->wk);
```

This is done so that the next BIO to be submitted is scheduled soon after the previous BIO has been successfully transferred. The first call to `submit_bio()` is done *without* using the work queue. This first call to `submit_bio()` is taking place without any problems; when called I call `submit_bio()` using a work item, the system crashes.

Any ideas?