# Producer/Consumer in the kernel space - Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, synchronization, linux-device-driver

I would like to have one thread to queue some requests in a request queue and another to serve these requests. The producer should wake up the consumer when there is a new request queued.

Is there anyone who has done this already or knows how to do it?

I have tried several tutorials on the internet and none of them really worked cleanly. They either miss a request, cause a system lockup/instability, or they just do not terminate.

Note: My question in essence is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742410/producer-consumer-implementation-in-a-block-device-driver). However, I wont be specific like the one who asked that question. Anyone who can/willing to help can just throw his two cents and may be we can work something out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Work Queues. Work Queues are simple, once you set up up your work queue, you use something like the following:

```
DECLARE_WORK(name, void (*function)(void *), void *data);
```

Your function call will be scheduled and called later, take a look at [this article](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-6).

I also highly recommend you this book: [Linux Device Drivers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0026OR2XQ)

**edit**: I just saw you already linked an SO post where they use work queues. Have you tried it out? You run into some issues? I suggest you start with an *really* simple example, just to try out if it's working. Implement your core functionality later.

**Update:**
From the [official Documentation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/workqueue.txt):

> Some users depend on the strict execution ordering of ST wq.  The
>   combination of @max_active of 1 and WQ_UNBOUND is used to achieve this
>   behavior.  Work items on such wq are always queued to the unbound
>   worker-pools and only one work item can be active at any given time
>   thus achieving the same ordering property as ST wq.

That way you will have a guaranteed FIFO execution of your workers. But be aware that the work may be executed on different CPUs. You have to use memory barriers to ensure visibility (eg. `wmb()`).

**Update:**

As @user2009594 mentioned, a single threaded wq can be created using the following macro defined in *linux/workqueue.h*:

```
#define create_singlethread_workqueue(name) \
alloc_workqueue("%s", WQ_UNBOUND | WQ_MEM_RECLAIM, 1, (name)))
```

Comment: My issue, is that there is no guarantee that there will be only thread  running the function that serves the requests. I need to have only one of those. I am trying to get rid of all complex synchronization stuff.

Comment: seems to be working. I found that they have already a macro definition that uses what you mentioned. It is 'create_singlethread_workqueue()'

Answer (score 0):

Multicast Netlink sockets can work here greatly. Recently I did the same; only difference was that my consumer was in kernel while producers in user space: same can be used in kernel only space.